# Pandas: output csv data to nested json with sorting

Tags: pandas, csv, to-json

Given the sample CSV data below, in a pandas DataFrame, how can I output to_json as follows

```
as_of
  category
     type
        subtype
           log: [
            #sorted by timestamp
            {timestamp: 1618879229, action: add, stale_timestamp: true},
            {timestamp: 1608879229, action: remove, stale_timestamp: None},
           ]

20210415
  apples
     A
        big
           log: [
            {timestamp: 1618879229, action: add, stale_timestamp: None},
           ]
        small
           log: [
            {timestamp: 1618879229, action: add, stale_timestamp: None},
            {timestamp: 1608879229, action: remove, stale_timestamp: None},
            {timestamp: 1518879229, action: add, stale_timestamp: None},
           ]
     B
        big
           log: [
            {timestamp: 1618879229, action: add, stale_timestamp: None},
           ]
```

Bonus if you can also help me go back to a DataFrame from the nested json!

| as_of | category | type | sub_type | action | timestamp | stale_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210415 | apples | A | big | add | 1618879229.6703315 |  |
| 20210415 | apples | A | small | add | 1618879229.6703315 |  |
| 20210415 | apples | B | big | add | 1618879229.6703315 |  |
| 20210415 | apples | B | small | add | 1618879229.6703315 |  |
| 20210415 | apples | C | big | add | 1618879229.6703315 |  |
| 20210415 | apples | C | small | add | 1618879229.6703315 |  |
| 202103 | oranges | sweet |  | add | 1616892142.6703315 |  |
| 202103 | oranges | sweet |  | remove | 1616632942.6703315 |  |
| 202103 | oranges | sweet |  | add | 1616200942.6703315 |  |
| 202103 | grapes | sweet |  | add | 1616200942.6703315 |  |
| 202102 | oranges | sweet |  | add | 1616200942.6703315 |  |
| 202102 | grapes | sweet |  | add | 1616200942.6703315 |  |
| 20210115 | apples | A | big | add | 1611103342.6703315 |  |
| 20210115 | apples | A | small | add | 1611103342.6703315 |  |
| 20210115 | apples | B | big | add | 1611103342.6703315 |  |
| 20210115 | apples | B | small | add | 1611103342.6703315 |  |
| 20210115 | apples | C | big | add | 1611103342.6703315 |  |
| 20210115 | apples | C | small | add | 1611103342.6703315 |  |
| 202101 | oranges | sweet |  | add | 1608424942.6703315 |  |
| 202101 | grapes | sweet |  | add | 1608424942.6703315 |  |
| 202012 | oranges | sweet |  | add | 1608424942.6703315 |  |
| 202012 | grapes | sweet |  | add | 1608424942.6703315 |  |
| 202011 | oranges | sweet |  | add | 1608424942.6703315 |  |
| 202011 | grapes | sweet |  | add | 1608424942.6703315 |  |
| 20201015 | apples | A | big | add | 1608424942.6703315 | True |
| 20201015 | apples | A | small | add | 1608424942.6703315 | True |
| 20201015 | apples | B | big | add | 1608424942.6703315 | True |
| 20201015 | apples | B | small | add | 1608424942.6703315 | True |
| 20201015 | apples | C | big | add | 1608424942.6703315 | True |
| 20201015 | apples | C | small | add | 1608424942.6703315 | True |
| 202010 | oranges | sweet |  | add | 1608424942.6703315 | True |
| 202010 | grapes | sweet |  | add | 1608424942.6703315 | True |

Comment: This is effectively a custom `orient` in the `.to_json` function of Pandas. The table provided would be more useful as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

First I converted the table into a CSV:

```
as_of,category,type,sub_type,action,timestamp,stale_timestamp
20210415,apples,A,big,add,1618879230,
20210415,apples,A,small,add,1618879230,
20210415,apples,B,big,add,1618879230,
20210415,apples,B,small,add,1618879230,
20210415,apples,C,big,add,1618879230,
20210415,apples,C,small,add,1618879230,
202103,oranges,sweet,,add,1616892143,
202103,oranges,sweet,,remove,1616632943,
202103,oranges,sweet,,add,1616200943,
202103,grapes,sweet,,add,1616200943,
202102,oranges,sweet,,add,1616200943,
202102,grapes,sweet,,add,1616200943,
20210115,apples,A,big,add,1611103343,
20210115,apples,A,small,add,1611103343,
20210115,apples,B,big,add,1611103343,
20210115,apples,B,small,add,1611103343,
20210115,apples,C,big,add,1611103343,
20210115,apples,C,small,add,1611103343,
202101,oranges,sweet,,add,1608424943,
202101,grapes,sweet,,add,1608424943,
202012,oranges,sweet,,add,1608424943,
202012,grapes,sweet,,add,1608424943,
202011,oranges,sweet,,add,1608424943,
202011,grapes,sweet,,add,1608424943,
20201015,apples,A,big,add,1608424943,TRUE
20201015,apples,A,small,add,1608424943,TRUE
20201015,apples,B,big,add,1608424943,TRUE
20201015,apples,B,small,add,1608424943,TRUE
20201015,apples,C,big,add,1608424943,TRUE
20201015,apples,C,small,add,1608424943,TRUE
202010,oranges,sweet,,add,1608424943,TRUE
202010,grapes,sweet,,add,1608424943,TRUE
```

The missing entries cause problems later in the JSON. That either needs to be fixed in the input file or in the Python converter. Also, some of the dates seem to be missing characters.

Because there isn't a pre-defined `orient` option in Pandas that suits this requirement, I wrote a custom dictionary and then converted the dictionary to JSON.

```
import pandas
import json
df = pandas.read_csv('sheet1.csv',header=None, dtype=str)

mydic = {}
for unique_col0 in df[0].unique():
    mydic[unique_col0] = {}
    
    sub_df = df[df[0]==unique_col0]
    for unique_col1 in sub_df[1].unique():
        mydic[unique_col0][unique_col1] = {}
        
        sub_sub_df = sub_df[sub_df[1]==unique_col1]
        for unique_col2 in sub_sub_df[2].unique():
            mydic[unique_col0][unique_col1][unique_col2] = {}
            
            sub_sub_sub_df = sub_sub_df[sub_sub_df[2]==unique_col2]
            for unique_col3 in sub_sub_sub_df[3].unique():
                mydic[unique_col0][unique_col1][unique_col2][unique_col3] = {'log':[]}
                
                for index in range(sub_sub_sub_df.shape[0]):
                    this_dict = {'timestamp': list(sub_sub_sub_df[5])[index],
                                 'action': list(sub_sub_sub_df[4])[index],
                                 'stale_timestamps': list(sub_sub_sub_df[6])[index]}
                    mydic[unique_col0][unique_col1][unique_col2][unique_col3]['log'].append(this_dict)
                
with open('output.json','w') as file_handle:
    json.dump(mydic,file_handle,indent=2)
```

The sample output provided by the asker isn't consistent with what actually gets produced by the Python implementation.